# NODEJS : Tests with supertest and mocha automatically pass on GitLab CI/CD

Tags: node.js, express, automated-tests, mocha.js, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run tests with mocha and supertest on an express nodejs app and the issue is that the GitLab runner on which the tests are executed automatically passes them even when they are wrong and should raise an error.

I have the correct outputs when I run them locally.

I'm new to these frameworks / technologies.

Here my project tree:
[image: project tree]

My tests:

```
var supertest = require("supertest");
var should = require("should");

var server = supertest.agent("http://localhost:8080");

// UNIT test begin

describe("SAMPLE unit test",function(){

 // #1 should return home page
server.get('/', function(req, res) {
tst = res.status(200).json({ "message": "hello world" });
console.log(tst);
});

it("should return home page",function(done){

// calling home page api
server
.get("/")
.expect("Content-type",/json/)
.expect(200) // THis is HTTP response
.end(function(err,res){
  // HTTP status should be 200
  //res.status.should.equal(200);
  // Error key should be false.
  //res.body.error.should.equal(false);
  console.log(res);
  done();
});
});
it("should login",function(done){
   // calling home page api
   server
   .post("/api/auth/signin")
   .send({"email":"emile.dadou@epsi.fr","password":"preudhomme"})
   .expect("Content-type",/json/)
   .expect(200) // THis is HTTP response
   .end(function(err,res){
   // HTTP status should be 200
   //res.status.should.equal(200);
   // Error key should be false.
   //res.body.error.should.equal(false);
   console.log(res);
   done();
  });
 });
 it("should raise an error",function(done){
  // calling home page api
  server
  .get("/gné") // this route doesn't exist
  .expect("Content-type",/json/)
  .expect(200) // THis is HTTP response
  .end(function(err,res){
  // HTTP status should be 200
  res.status.should.equal(200);
  // Error key should be false.
  res.body.error.should.equal(false);
  console.log(res);
  done();
  });
});
});
```

And here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file :

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - build
  - tests

build:
 type: build
 stage: build
 script:
   - ls -l
   - npm i
   - npm run build --if-present
   - npm start server.js
   - npm test

tests:
  type: test
  stage: tests
  script:
   - npm i
   - npm test
```

So after a push the pipeline starts and after I have these outputs:
[image: gitlab ci/cd output]

on the other when I execute the tests locally I have the right outputs (2 pass and 1 failing) like this:

[image: local tests output]

Is there something that I'm missing or done wrong?
How can I have the same outputs in GitLab?

Comment: After trying different configurations i found out that the issue came from the server that i was talking to wasn't running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying different configurations i found out that the issue came from the server that i was talking to wasn't running